# Пунктуация в сложном предложении смешанного типа

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Здравствуйте, подскажите верно ли в предположении ниже расславлены знаки препинания?

Кому-то сразу дано многое - внешность, деньги, благополучная семья - и для него открыты все дороги; кому-то не дано ничего, и он должен разгребать грязь вокруг себя, чтобы выбраться, чтобы ступить на тот же путь, что и первый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кому-то сразу дано многое - внешность, деньги, благополучная семья, и для него открыты все дороги; кому-то не дано ничего, и он должен разгребать грязь вокруг себя, чтобы выбраться, чтобы ступить на тот же путь, что и первый.

Пояснение

При обособлении приложений одно тире ставится, если за  приложением в соответствии со структурой предложения СЛЕДУЕТ ЗАПЯТАЯ (в сложном предложении, перед деепричастным оборотом или между однородными членами с бессоюзной связью).  В этом случае считается, что второе тире «ПОГЛОЩАЕТСЯ» запятой.

Пример

Стоял чудесный апрельский день – лучшее время в Арктике, и мы отправились на прогулку.

Comment: А точка с запятой полагаю верно стоит?

Comment: У Лопатина: "При значительной распространенности части бессоюзного сложного предложения могут разделяться точкой с запятой; предпочтительна точка с запятой, если внутри частей сложного предложения имеются запятые — показатели их внутреннего членения". В форме БСП   второе предложение распространяет содержание первого, но между ними более тесная связь, чем в случае постановки точки и деления предложения на самостоятельные части.

Comment: А что касательно первого тире? Почему именно тире, вроде бы по правилам нужно двоеточие ставить. Посколько идет конкретизация и подразумевается "а именно"
"Кому-то сразу дано многое: внешность, деньги, благополучная семья, и для него открыты все дороги; кому-то не дано ничего, и он должен разгребать грязь вокруг себя, чтобы выбраться, чтобы ступить на тот же путь, что и первый."

Comment: Это по классическим правилам рекомендуется ставить двоеточие, но даже в классических произведениях можно увидеть тире, заменяющее двоеточие. Двоеточие - это остановка в речи, подчеркнутая пауза, предупреждающая о последующем раскрытии темы.  (При постановке тире   тема дается в виде присоединительной конструкции, без специальной паузы/остановки). В нашем случае предложение является значительно распространенным, поэтому нет возможности уделять особое внимание однородному ряду,  в противном случае основное содержание не будет раскрыто должным образом.

Comment: Вы безгранично правы Вера. Я тоже думаю именно так. Там не паузы и особо нет конкретизации. Тогда будьте любезны посетете еще одну проблему http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/417291/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%86%D1%8B/417295?noredirect=1#comment416212_417295

Comment: Давайте чуть позже. Я не очень поняла тему в целом, поэтому не стала ее комментировать, а сейчас времени, к сожалению, нет.

Answer (score 1):

Кому-то сразу дано многое: внешность, деньги, благополучная семья, и для него открыты все дороги; кому-то не дано ничего, и он должен разгребать грязь вокруг себя, чтобы выбраться, чтобы ступить на тот же путь, что и первый.

Розенталь: "Если однородные члены, стоящие после обобщающего слова, не заканчивают собой предложения, то перед ними ставится двоеточие, а после них – тире, например. А снаружи все: и оконницы, и коньки, и ворота – оторочено кружевом грубоватой деревянной резьбы (Б. Полевой).

Примечание. Постановка перед тире также запятой в качестве дополнительного пунктуационного знака связана с условиями контекста, т.е. обусловлена каким-либо другим правилом ... Если постановка запятой требуется структурой последней части предложения (стоящей после перечисления), то тире опускается и ставится только запятая, например: Владелец тщательно осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как-то: муку, пеньку, мед и прочее, но покупает только небольшие безделушки... (Гоголь)".

Comment: В том-то и дело, что тут не нужно двоеточия. Оно тут "не чувствуется".

Answer (score 0):

Кому-то сразу дано многое: внешность, деньги, благополучная семья - и для него открыты все дороги; кому-то не дано ничего, и он должен разгребать грязь вокруг себя, чтобы выбраться, чтобы ступить на тот же путь, что и первый.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что тут не нужно двоеточия. Оно тут "не чувствуется".

Answer (score 0):

Приложение как синтаксическая категория выделяется не по смысловому, а по формальному основанию (выражено существительным), поэтому обороты, вроде приведенного Вами, могут быть квалифицированы на формальном основании как приложение с пояснительным значением, а на смысловом основании как вставная конструкция. Это дает возможность двоякого формления таких предложений:

***>а) Кому-то сразу дано многое - внешность, деньги, благополучная семья, - и для него открыты все дороги...***

***>б) Кому-то сразу дано многое - внешность, деньги, благополучная семья, и для него открыты все дороги...***

Грамма.ру.