# Знаки препинания или спасите от запятой-убийцы

Tags: пунктуация

Думаете(тут не хочу ставить запятую) я, взрослый, понимаешь, человек***,*** кандидат наук, понимаешь, этого не предполагал?

1. Могу ли я не ставить запятую после "думаете". Ну не просится она по характеру разговорной речи там.
2. Возмущает запятая, выделенная звездочками. Может нужно тире или точка с запятой, или что еще? Прошу Вас, уважаемые знатоки, не надо правил, просто скажите как правильно в данном случае. Я запомню.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаете, я, взрослый, понимаешь, человек, кандидат наук, понимаешь, этого не предполагал?

1) Запятые расставлены верно, но предложение **не читается из-за большого количества запятых.** Поэтому предлагается обособить ряд приложений с помощью **тире** (кстати, и в устной речи, скорее всего, этот ряд выделяется **паузами**).

2) Также вспомним **о  самом общем назначении знаков препинания:** письмо должно ТОЧНО И ПОЛНОСТЬЮ выражать содержание высказывания, при этом  знаки препинания должны способствовать ЯСНОСТИ В ИЗЛОЖЕНИИ МЫСЛЕЙ, в отделении одной части высказывания от другой.

3) Тогда получаем:

Думаете, я - взрослый, понимаешь, человек,  кандидат наук, понимаешь, - этого не предполагал?

Пояснение

1) Запятую после "думаете" **убрать нельзя, это вводное слово,** но отсутствие паузы в устной речи не должно смущать. Чем сложнее предложение, тем меньше у вводного слова шансов быть выделенным паузой, так как интонация выражает только старшие структуры. В этом случае запятая соответствует **только грамматическому**, а не интонационному принципу.

2) Разговорная речь  может иметь определенные особенности оформления, но при этом **она должна подчиняться общим принципам пунктуации**,  и эта задача еще более трудная, чем найти подходящее правило. Каждый  особый знак должен объясняться с точки зрения ГРАММАТИКИ, ИНТОНАЦИИ и СМЫСЛА.

Comment: Вариант с тире очень даже неплох. В остальном Вы для меня слишком умны. Голова вскипела, пока пытался все это понять. Благодарю.

Касательно интонационной паузы в популярном выражении "думаешь я..." Вот признайтесь, что там ОЧЕНЬ ЧАСТО никогда никто интонацией паузу после "думаешь" не ставит. Говорят сразу, более того, часто интонационная пауза ставится ПОСЛЕ этого выражения: думаешь я (ПАУЗА) пошел бы туда?
Вот такие пироги )))) Понятно, что ничего не понятно.

Comment: Тогда я проще объясню. 1) Приложение выделяем, делая вставкой с помощью тире   и пауз,  то есть у нас получается два плана   речи. 2) "Глагольное" вводное слово всегда обособляется, так как членом предложения его не сделаешь (но при этом пауза необязательна). 3)  Разговорная речь не имеет привилегий и подчиняется ОБЩИМ  правилам, но КОНКРЕТНОЕ решение может быть нестандартным и требует от автора большего искусства.

Comment: Спасибо, Вера. 
Сам текст  - это и есть главное и единственное искусство автора, а вот пунктуация либо подчиняется тексту, либо опускается, если при этом текст начинает "страдать".

Comment: Есть еще искусство обращения с пунктуацией, которая при правильном ее понимании и применении может быть очень ПЛАСТИЧНА,  украсит любой текст и ни в коем случае не заставит его страдать. Для это  надо воспринимать правила пунктуации не как набор жестких инструкций, а как дополнительный инструмент для творчества. Здесь ситуация такова, как везде: или вы пунктуацию, или она вас.

Comment: "или она вас" Вот я о чем и говорил - "запятая убийца!" ))) Вера, дайте ваш вконтакте или в фейсбуке. Хочу дружить ) Я просто понять не могу, как тут в личку написать. Порядочность и пунктуальность, я хотел сказать пунктационность гарантирую. )

Comment: Хотите подружиться с запятыми?  Для Вас, а также для всех желающих дружить мой почтовый ящик: vera260919@mail.ru

Answer (score 1):

Возмущает... А вы не возмущайтесь. *Взрослый человек, кандидат наук, этого не предполагал.* Вот и всё. Потом на это уже можно, понимашь, нанизывать, понимашь, всякие разговорные, сорные, понимашь, словечки.

Comment: Возмущаюсь, именно потому, что здесь запятая визуально воспринимается как лишняя. И именно потому, что до нее и после нее идет тоже запятые, но немного другого "характера". Я ищу именно знак на замену, а вы хотите убить мои мечты.

Answer (score 1):

А почему Вас возмущает эта запятая? Она на месте, разделяет однородные приложения.Никаких тире и точек с запятой здесь не надо. Возмущают здесь только сорные вводные словечки"понимаешь", но они здесь как художественная особенность, показывают волнение героя.

А отсутствие запятой после "Думаете" не возмущает?

Думаете, я, взрослый, понимаешь, человек, кандидат наук, понимаешь, этого не предполагал?

Без обособленного приложения будет так:Думаете, я  этого не предполагал? А кто именно я? -взрослый, понимаешь, человек, кандидат наук, понимаешь-однородные приложения, осложнённые авторскими вводными словами"понимаешь".

Comment: "А отсутствие запятой после "Думаете" не возмущает?"

А она только обязательна? Прям так строго правилами? (Автор принципиально не ставил тут запятую именно потому, что герой не делал паузы, когда это говорил.)

Comment: После ''думаете" запятая обязательна! Это вводное слово.

Comment: Вы уверены? Тут мне один человек вот как ответил А на разговорную речь не всегда можно перенести правила, за исключением тех случаев, когда можно найти аналоги между разговорной и литературной речью. О знаках препинания в разговорной речи можете почитать у Розенталя. Если хотите, могу дать ссылку. Именно там об этом и говорится. Так что я опирался на Розенталя, а не выдумывал от себя.
Автор настаивает на разговорном характере речи и запятую там ставить не хочет. Значит,,,,,,,,,,,,, получается автор может так поступить?

Comment: Это не касается вводных слов. Это лишь касается спорных разговорных конструкций, когда нельзя провести грань между разговорной и литературной речью. Это не значит: где хочу, там и ставлю, где не хочу - не ставлю.

Comment: "Этот один человек''  - я.

Answer (score 0):

Ваше предложение носит типично разговорный характер, а пунктуация в большинстве случаев не распространяется на предложения разговорной речи,поэтому говорить о "правильности-неправильности" не всегда можно. В вашем случае вполне можно обойтись или точкой с запятой или просто точкой. Но и запятая не будет ошибкой.

Comment: Вашими словами, да... Я очень бы хотел тоже так думать, но Вы неправы. Разговорных характер не отменял правил русского языка.

Comment: Уважаемый Денис!  Правила придумываю не я. А на разговорную речь не всегда можно перенести правила, за исключением тех случаев, когда можно найти аналоги между разговорной и литературной речью. О знаках препинания в разговорной речи можете почитать у Розенталя. Если хотите, могу дать ссылку. Именно там об этом и говорится. ***Так что я опирался на Розенталя, а не выдумывал от себя.***

Comment: Уточнение: в вашем примере действительно нужно запятая, т.к. это однородные приложения, а не разные предложения. Я говорил о точки с запятой, т.к. разделил на два предложения: Думаете я, взрослый, понимаешь, человек; кандидат наук, понимаешь, этого не предполагал? Меня сбили с толку авторские разговорные вводные слова.